# Update table without using REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql

My application stores some logs locally into a table but at the same time it also stores the same data on a remote server database. If for some reason the connection to the remote server is broken then the application continues storing the data locally. At the end of work the application has to copy the local data to the remote server.

The tables on both sides have the same structure but there is no primary key defined so it is useless to use `REPLACE INTO`. Is there any other way to copy data from the local database to the remote database but not copy records that already exist in the remote database?

This is how the table looks:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| ProductionID| Start      | Factor     |
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| 1123        | 1          |   Y        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| 1123        | 2          |   N        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| 1123        | 3          |   Y        |
+-------------+------------+------------+     
| 2212        | 6          |   Y        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| 2212        | 4          |   Y        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a primary key for your table. If you want to prevent duplicates looking at all the fields, you can put all the columns in the primary key

```
ALTER TABLE your_tbl
ADD CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (ProductionID,Start,Factor)
```